Building a NSIS script that can create a Conda virtual environment once installation is completed
I am trying to build an installation setup for a Python based package and am using NSIS for it. However, once the installation is complete, I need to create a virtual environment for the package inside the installation directory which I am not able to using the NSIS script. I tried using ExecWait command, but to no help. Is there any better to way to create a virtual environment and install all the packages from Requirements.txt?
I entered the command for virtual environment creation in a batch script createEnv.bat:
@CALL conda create -n env python=3.10
Subsequently this script was called from NSIS script as:
SetOutPath $INSTDIR
ExecWait '"createEnv.bat"'

The command prompt screen comes up while this line is read but nothing is executed. Please let me know if there is some more elegant way to get this done.
